# How to combine or merge character datatype in sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, sqldatatypes

I am having an issue. I have looked for some help online but none of them showed accurate result. I will really appreciate if anyone can help me in this regard.

Here is the scenario:

I have a db_table 'A' where I have to merge the rows that is duplicate also I have to add another column that is in Character datatype 
it is something like this.

Table A

```
ID  |SCORE(character)
-------------------

90  |10000
93  |00005
94  |02000
90  |02000
94  |00005
```

The output will be:

```
ID  |SCORE(character)
-------------
90  |12000
93  |00005
94  |02005
```

Comment: if all of the values in the SCORE column are numeric, you should be able to use `Sum(SCORE)` and `Group By ID`

Comment: You can try casting the character column to a numeric type, then you can group and sum

Comment: Fix you table, don't store numeric values in character columns.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for replying well the datatype is character and it has been created this way. I cant change it in production also. 
I am having trouble syntax wise to write/build the logic with if statement, if anyone can help I will really appreciate that.

Comment: @Tab Alleman: I am sorry if I did not explain the question clear enough that you have marked as duplicate: but I hope this will make it clear:

it is not sum or add function per se. it is mostly 5 digit char datatype number and I have made it first into as 10000, 02000, 00300, 00040,00005 and add them if any 'ID' has more then one value under 'SCORE'. 
For more clarification, please check the Demonstration I have up there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`. Try like:

```
SELECT id,sum( convert (int,score)) from myTable group by ID
```

Comment: @miguel  thanks YOU :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for such prompt response. I got it. As I have already mentioned I am new to SQL, so please consider before Mark this question as negative. Other may get help from that too.

Peace

Answer (score 0):

It's simply

```
SELECT ID,
       SUM(ISNULL(TRY_CAST(Score AS INT), 0))
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select ID, REPLICATE('0',5-LEN(SUM(CAST(SCORE as int))))+ CAST(SUM(CAST(SCORE as int)) as varchar) as Score
from Table 
group by ID
```

Comment: I did try your code but it is adding it as 00300+00005 as 00008 (the desired output is 00305) . But I really appreciate your response.